# Node.js прочитать файл не сохраняя на сервере

Tags: node.js, файлы, express

Как можно в node.js сделать чтение текстового файла, загруженного пользователем, не сохраняя его на сервере? Использую express и body-parser

Если можно, пример кода

**UPD:**
На странице есть input с типом "file". Пользователь выбирает файл с диска и делает POST-запрос на страницу. Мне нужно только прочитать этот файл. Можно ли как-то это сделать, не сохраняя его на сервере

Comment: надо спрашивать по нормальному ,а не играть в ромашку, что значит "загруженного пользователем"? загружен он куда, если на сервер то он уже там сохранён. Хотите нормальный ответ сделайте нормальный вопрос

Comment: сорри, дополнил

Comment: ну и чем не подходил мой ответ, или тебе надо пример кода сервера, и что значит прочитать файл?, файл придёт в переменной, делай с ним чего хочешь

Comment: весь текст из файла сразу будет в переменной? А если это не текстовый файл, что будет в переменной?

Comment: Будет нечитабельный мусор, данные будут скорее всего в BASE64, я просто по ряду причин express  не люблю и не использую, в рамках чистой ноды я знаю как это сделать, в рамках express"а нужно делать app.post и из полученного ответа вытаскивать данные, сами данные будут приходить в виде стрима и надо его склеивать connect-busboy, multer или connect-multiparty

Comment: для этого я использую body-parser. UPD: Только что проверил. В переменной записывается только имя файла

Comment: потому что данные идут стримом и подгружаются позже, для их склеивания и используют multer  и т.д.